# How to save select option in a nested form group

Tags: angular

I'm showing a list of items to users and need to save the item they select in a form.

Here is my form:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  name: [''],
  course: this.fb.group({
    name: [''],
    teacher: [''],
  })   
});       

this.courseService.getAccounts()
    .subscribe(courses => this.courses = courses);
```

Here is the .html file:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div>
  <label>Courses</label>
  <select formGroupName="course" >
    <option *ngFor="let course of courses">
      {{course.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
</form>
```

This way, users can see the list of the courses (e.g., 5 items), but selecting an item is not saved in the form!

I tried:
`<option *ngFor="let course of courses" formControlName="name"> {{course.name}} </option>`, but then the select has 5 options that only one has a vale (the previously selected course).

I think when I use `formControlName` then the option gets its value from `form` and not `*ngFor`, therefore, only one option has value.

Is there any way that I can show all options and save the selected option in the form by `formControlName` or something similar?

P.S. if possible, I prefer to do not use `patchValue()` or `setValue()`.

Update: How courses and users look like:

```
courses: [
    {name:"mathematics", teacher:"John Doe"},
    {name:"science", teacher:"Jane Doe"},
    ...
]
user: {
    name: "Alex Doe",
    course:{
        name: "science",
        teacher: "Jane Doe"
    }
}
```

Imagine Alex has originally selected science. When he opens his profile, he will see science as his course (i.e., the default selected value for `<select></select>` is science), but by clicking on it, he sees the list of all available courses and if he wants, he can select mathematics, and then science is replaced by mathematics.

Comment: I don't get your question. The code is working as intended: you have a select which can have multiple values. Once you select one of the them, the select has this new value. 
Maybe you want to check when it is changed? Check out the valueChanges method of your Control, which gives you an Observable to subscribe to. https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges

Comment: @user6781 could you share the data, like a simple mock of how `courses` and the `users` array will look like?

Comment: @naren-murali I've updated my question. Can you please check if it is now clear what I'm looking for?

Comment: @thomasgainant I don't want multiple values. I've updated the question with an example, can you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using formGroup, you can use form controls to handle the select, like this.

```
this.form.addControl('users', new FormControl(''));
```

In the example you add a control to the form control and binding the data. I recommend you to use mat-select

Comment: This way I am adding a new formControl to my form. But I already have the required formControl in my form.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the data, please find below a working example, please go through the stackblitz and let me know if any questions.

main.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="name"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Courses</label>
      <select formControlName="course">
        <option *ngFor="let course of courses" [value]="course">
          {{course.name}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  name = 'Angular';
  courses: any[] = [];
  form = this.fb.group({
    name: [''],
    course: [''],
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private testService: TestService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCourses();
  }

  getCourses() {
    this.subscription.add(
      this.testService.getCourses().subscribe((courses: any[]) => {
        this.courses = courses;
        this.getUser();
      })
    );
  }

  getUser() {
    this.subscription.add(
      this.testService.getUser().subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.form.patchValue({
          name: response?.name,
          course: response?.course,
        });
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TestService {
  constructor() {}

  getCourses() {
    return of([
      { name: 'mathematics', teacher: 'John Doe' },
      { name: 'science', teacher: 'Jane Doe' },
    ]);
  }

  getUser() {
    return of({
      name: 'Alex Doe',
      course: {
        name: 'science',
        teacher: 'Jane Doe',
      },
    });
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nsovad)

Comment: Thanks @naren-murali for your answer, I couldn't integrate it in my code, but changing my code I could get it running. Here is what I've changed: ```<div formGroupName="course">      <label>Courses</label> <select formControlName="name">  <option  *ngFor="let course of courses" [value]="course.name" > {{course.name}}  </option> </select>
    </div>```